# How to solve regex with AND and OR and NOT with combination of word in python

Tags: python, regex

I have below lines,

https://regex101.com/r/uHCT7x/1

```
/var/log/data/folder1/apache/data/log

/var/log/data/folder4.data/jdk/data/log
```

I tried:

```
(/var/log/data)*(apache)
(/var/log/data)(?<!apache)(jdk/data/log)
```

here, `/var/log/data/` and `data/log` is fixed data in whole file.
I want to match like,

First, Valid if match with `/var/log/data` AND match with `apache`  both must in like.

Second, Valid if match with `/var/log/data`, NOT in `apache` and End with `jdk/data/log`match.

Want to do separation with this data & two different regex to identify it.

Comment: Do you want to match them both in the same output, or separate patterns? What should NOT match?

Comment: So `/var/log/data/folder1/apache/data/log` is a valid match or invalid?

Comment: @PacketLoss I want to separate both, for 2nd, `/var/log/data`  match, NOT match `apache`, match with `jdk/data/log`

Comment: So are you looking for 2 different regex for both cases?

Comment: @anubhava yes two different regex

Answer (score 2):

> First, Valid if match with `/var/log/data` AND match with `apache`

Use this simple regex:

```
^/var/log/data/.*/apache\b
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/uHCT7x/4)

This regex matches a line starting with `/var/log/data/` and matches `apache` anywhere after matching `/var/log/data/` at the start.

> Second, Valid if match with `/var/log/data`, NOT in apache and End with `jdk/data/log`

Use this regex:

```
^/var/log/data/(?!.*/apache\b).*/jdk/data/log$
```

- This regex matches a line starting with `/var/log/data/` and ending with `/jdk/data/log`.
- `(?!.*/apache\b)` is a negative lookahead to fail the match if `/apache` word comes anywhere after matching starting pattern.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/uHCT7x/3)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to match `start:middle:end` you can keep it pretty simple.

```
string = '''/var/log/data/folder1/apache/data/log
/var/log/data/folder4.data/jdk/data/log
/var/log/data/folder55/apache/data/log
/var/log/data/foler/jdk/data/log'''
```

Apache

```
re.findall(r'/var/log/data/.*?/apache.*', string)
#['/var/log/data/folder1/apache/data/log', '/var/log/data/folder55/apache/data/log']
```

Non-Apache

```
re.findall(r'/var/log/data/(?!.*apache).*?/jdk/data/log', string)
#['/var/log/data/folder4.data/jdk/data/log', '/var/log/data/foler/jdk/data/log']
```

Comment: `/var/log/data/.*?/apache.*`  working well but for second, I want to add like `NOT apache`

Comment: @Nullpointer I've added the regex to ignore results with `apache`